# Dealing with grouped dataset in R

Tags: r, dplyr, tapply

I have a dataset like:

```
+----+-------+---------+----------+--+
| id | time  |  event  | timediff |  |
+----+-------+---------+----------+--+
|  1 | 15.00 | install | -        |  |
|  1 | 15.30 | sale    | 00.30    |  |
|  1 | 16.00 | sale    | 00.30    |  |
|  2 | 15.00 | sale    | -        |  |
|  2 | 15.30 | sale    | 0.30     |  |
|  3 | 16.00 | install | -        |  |
|  4 | 15.00 | install | -        |  |
|  5 | 13.00 | install | -        |  |
|  5 | 14.00 | sale    | 01.00    |  |
+----+-------+---------+----------+--+
```

I want to clean this dataset:
I want to exclude the ids for which the first (and the next n..) events are sales but not installs. 
I want to exclude the ids for which there is an install but no sales (those ids are indeed the unique ones)

Obtaining finally a result like:

```
+----+-------+---------+----------+
| id | time  |  event  | timediff |
+----+-------+---------+----------+
|  1 | 15.00 | install | -        |
|  1 | 15.30 | sale    | 0.30     |
|  1 | 16.00 | sale    | 0.30     |
|  5 | 13.00 | install | -        |
|  5 | 14.00 | sale    | 01.00    |
+----+-------+---------+----------+
```

How can I do that in R? is there any specific package for data manipulation or I can just use if formulas? Should I use tapply?

Comment: Anything you've already tried yourself? Why did it not work?

Comment: In the future try to post code to reproduce your data, as the above table-like format cannot be easily turned into an R object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the example, we can group by 'id' and `filter` the 'event' column that has `first` element as 'install' and 2nd as 'sale' to get the expected output.

```
df1 %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  filter(first(event)=='install' & event[2L]=='sale')
    id  time   event timediff
#  (int) (dbl)   (chr)    (dbl)
#1     1  15.0 install       NA
#2     1  15.3    sale      0.3
#3     1  16.0    sale      0.3
#4     5  13.0 install       NA
#5     5  14.0    sale      1.0
```

Or if all the elements except first one should be 'sale', we create a logical variable ('ind') by comparing the `first` element as 'install' and the successive elements as 'sale' (using `lead`), then `filter` groups where `all` the 'ind' are TRUE.  If needed, we can remove the 'ind' column using `select`.

```
 df1 %>% 
     group_by(id) %>%
     mutate(ind= first(event)=='install' & lead(event, default='sale')=='sale') %>%
     filter(all(ind)) %>% 
     ungroup() %>% 
     select(-ind)
```

---

Or we can use `data.table`., grouped by 'id', `if` the number of rows is greater than 1 (`.N >1`),  first element is 'install' (`event[1L]=='install'`) and `all` the rest of the elements are 'sale', then we get the Subset of Data.table (`.SD`).

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df1)[, if(.N > 1 & event[1L]=='install' & all(event[2:.N]=='sale')) .SD, by = id]
#   id time   event timediff
#1:  1 15.0 install       NA
#2:  1 15.3    sale      0.3
#3:  1 16.0    sale      0.3
#4:  5 13.0 install       NA
#5:  5 14.0    sale      1.0
```

Comment: it works! but I dont get quite well the logic of the parameter [2L]. What does this mean?